# Multiple Kinects using Kinect for Windows SDK 1.5

Tags: windows, sdk, kinect, hresult

I'm trying to make two Kinects getting along under the same application. I've tried to start all the connected Kinects (by calling the Start() method), but only one has the "isRunning" flag set on true. Does anyone know why is only one sensor running?

LE: I connected the two kinects on different USB controllers ... same problem. I've enabled all exceptions, and I get this, when the start method is called for the second kinect:

```
This API has returned an exception from an HRESULT: 0x830100AA
```

The stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Kinect.KinectExceptionHelper.CheckHr(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.Kinect.NuiSensor.NuiInitialize(UInt32 dwFlags)
   at Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor.Initialize(SensorOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Kinect.KinectSensor.Start()
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the skeletal tracking and now both kinect sensors are running. But now the question that arises: Why it's not possible to enable also the skeletal tracking?

Answer (score 4):

Kinect sensor requires a lot of USB bandwidth so each Kinect should be connected to a separate USB controller. Try connecting both of them to different USB host controllers. You can also verify the status under "Microsoft.Kinect" node in Device manager.